# Create date column using year and month columns to yyyymmdd

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a year column that contains things like 2013, 2012, etc and a month column that displays 1-12. I need to use these columns to create a date that always pulls the last day of the month that the year and month represents as yyyymmdd. For example, if year = 2018 and Month = 3, I need the date to display as 20180331. The year and month fields are numeric. I am using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could shoe horn it this way:

select REPLACE(CAST(EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(2018,2,1)) as varchar(20)), '-','')

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a formula that works, although the answer above is smaller in code and may be a more efficient way to accomplish the same thing, which I can test out. Here is the code that I was able to get to work for those interested.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),eomonth(CAST(CAST(FV_RPT_EMPLOYEECENSUS_ASOF.HRYEAR AS VARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(FV_RPT_EMPLOYEECENSUS_ASOF.HRPERIOD AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(01 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) AS DATE)),112)
```

Comment: Start thinking about your datatypes. A year will (or should, otherwise bad things happen) always have 4 digits - so why varchar(4) and not char(4)? Style 112 is also fixed length. There is no reason to use a numeric literal - 01 - and cast it to varchar(2) - just specify the correct string literal '01'. Nor does it need to be cast to varchar when it is 2 chars. Lastly, you should let the consumer of a resultset define how data is formatted - you might like yyyymmdd while someone else might prefer a different order or separators or whatnot.